# Position Sticky Not working on flex parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

Cant seem to make position sticky to work.

I have a display flex content where the left is so long that I want the right div to stick until the end of the left div

my structure is this

```
<div class="listing-details-flex">
      <div class="listing-details-left">long content</div>
      <div class="listing-details-right">form</div>
</div>
```

How can I make position sticky work on the right div

I tried using overflow auto on parent flex div still not working I also tried encapsulating the right div into another container and setting the height of that not working also

Comment: Since this is a CSS question, please share the CSS code for this.